# Confusion with arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, cohen-macaulay

I'm a bit struck about this fact; I think it's really a silly question, but I'm not completely sure about it.

Let $X\subseteq \mathbf{P}^m$ be a projective variety; choose the best hypotheses possible, that is a noetherian separated scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$. Assume also $X$ is smooth. Then I have the following definitions:

- $X$ is *arithmetically Cohen-Macaulay* if the coordinate ring is Cohen-Macaulay;
- $X$ is *(geometrically) Cohen-Macaulay* if every local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

I know that these two definition must be different, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I know that Cohen-Macaulay is a strongly local property (i.e. a ring is Cohen-Macaulay iff every localization is) and this seems to contradict the thesis.

Could someone help with an example?

Comment: The confusion seems to come from exactly what the phrase "coordinate ring" should mean in the definition of ACM. There are in fact two conventions, but let's stick to one: it should mean the _homogeneous coordinate ring_ of $X$, in other words the ring $R=k[x_0,\ldots,x_m]/I$ where $I$ is the homogeneous ideal of $X$. Now we are asking that $R$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. That is equivalent, as you say, to every localisation of $R$ being CM. What does this means about $X$? Well, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the cone over $X$. So after deleting the origin, we get an $\mathbf A^1$-bundle over $X$..

Comment: Therefore if $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is CM, $X$ must be too. On the other hand, if $X$ is CM, then $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is too, *except possibly at the origin*. So this is where the difference can happen: depending on how $X$ is embedded in projective space, the cone $\operatorname{Spec} R$ can have a bad (non-CM) singularity at the origin, even if $X$ has no such singularities I don't know examples offhand, but I believe there are some on MathOverflow.

Comment: Typical example is take your favorite smooth projective variety of say dimension $d$ and embed it using a big complete linear system in $\mathbb{P}^N$ for very large $N$. Then project to $\mathbb{P}^{2d+1}$ which still gives an embedding. Easy to check that $R$ as above is not CM.